# Azure SQL Database - Storage costs

Tags: database, azure, storage

With in an Azure SQL Database storage shows as Used, Remaining, Allocated and Max
[image: Storage]

My understanding was that we are only charged for the Used space not allocated or max.  However a colleague has questioned this as the cost estimate is based on the Max storage

MS Azure cost estimator is unclear

Comment: I _think_ you'll be charged for "allocated space", quoting from their pricing page `you are charged for [storage type, depends on tier] that you provision`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the model you choose.

For DTU the storage costs are included in the DTU plan you pick. So as far as storage costs go it doesn't matter if you use 1GB or 250GB as long as the plan supports your maximum size.

For VCore you pay for your provisioned storage. In other words the maximum you've set is what you're paying for. From the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql#vcore-storage-costs):

> For data storage, you're charged for the provisioned storage based upon the maximum database or pool size you select. The cost doesn't change unless you reduce or increase that maximum.